# Using fasd to open a file or directory in emacsclient

Tags: terminal, emacs

I'm trying to open files found with [fasd](https://github.com/clvv/fasd) in `emacsclient`. I'm using `fasd -e emacsclient -c -a ''` set to an alias. Nothing happens when I call the alias, I just get a new prompt. I've tried using Emacs directly with `fasd -e emacs` which works fine. Please let me know if you know what the problem might be.

**EDIT**: (As requested. Not much else to see though.)

---

**alias**
`alias fed="fasd -e emacsclient -c -a ''"`

**fasd.zsh**

```
#
# only init if installed.
fasd_cache="$HOME/.fasd-init-bash"
if [ "$(command -v fasd)" -nt "$fasd_cache" -o ! -s "$fasd_cache" ]; then
  eval "$(fasd --init posix-alias zsh-hook zsh-ccomp zsh-ccomp-install zsh-wcomp zsh-wc\
omp-install)" >| "$fasd_cache"
fi
source "$fasd_cache"
unset fasd_cache


# jump to recently used items
alias a='fasd -a' # any
alias s='fasd -si' # show / search / select
alias d='fasd -d' # directory
alias f='fasd -f' # file
alias z='fasd_cd -d' # cd, same functionality as j in autojump
alias zz='fasd_cd -d -i' # interactive directory jump
```

**results**

Should open ~/Downloads/ in `emacsclient`, but does nothing:

```
~ » fed downlo                                                                
~ »
```

Comment: What is fasd, and how are you using it exactly? Copy-paste the commands you ran and all relevant configuration files (for fasd and for your shell).

Comment: I don't know anything about fasd but what about the difference between your 'fed' alias using -e emacsclient vs the manual way (that works) using -e emacs?

Comment: I solved the issue. But you should check out `fasd`. It keeps a list of recent files sorted by frequency of use and lets you jump to them through fuzzy matching. Really saves a lot of typing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand how fasd works, but your alias doesn't make sense.

> ```
> alias fed="fasd -e emacsclient -c -a "
> ```

You're passing `emacsclient` as an argument to the `-e` option, then `-c` and `-a` are more options passed to `fasd`. The final space means that the word after the alias will undergo alias expansion, e.g. `fed a foo` expands to `fasd -e emacsclient -c -a fasd -a foo`.

Given that `fasd` doesn't understand `-c` as an option, I presume that you meant to call `emacsclient -c -a ''`, i.e. to call `emacsclient` with the three arguments `-c`, `-a` and an empty string.

Given the way `fasd` interprets the argument to `-e`:

> ```
>           e*) o="${o#?}"; if [ "$o" ]; then # there are characters after "-e"
>                 local exec="$o" # anything after "-e"
> (…)
>       $exec "$res"
> ```

there's no way to pass an empty string as one of the words in the command. Define an auxiliary function instead (an alias would also work here).

```
emacsclient_c () {
  emacsclient -c -a '' "$@"
}
alias fed='fasd -e emacsclient_c'
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure what I was thinking when I thought those arguments would be directed to emacsclient.

Comment: And yes, I forgot to add the empty string to my second example.

Answer (score 0):

Though according to the documentation an alias should have worked, I solved the problem by creating a shell function and passing the fasd search phrase as an argument.

```
fed() {
    emacsclient -c -a '' `fasd -f -a $1`;
}
```

Instead of telling `fasd` to open the file in `emacsclient`, I just have `fasd` return the path to `emacsclient`.

Answer (score 0):

How I got it working is just aliassing the following 
This pipes the file to 'emacsclient -n -c' found with fasd. 
 
`alias e='f -e "emacsclient -n -c"'`

So I can type `e exam` to open `example.txt` in an emacs client.

Comment: @JohnMiliter OP almost had his alias working, the only thing that needed fixing was adding quotation marks around the command `emacsclient -n -c` which is what I did.
I had the very same 'problem' and came across this post.